# Is it acceptable to add a 句号 (full stop 。) at the end of a sentence ending in a 省略号 (ellipsis ……)?

Tags: punctuation

> 我去过了很多国家，日本、中国、美国、加拿大、印度……
> <sub>郑丽杰, 刘悦, 21天政府HSK6级写作, p. 44. ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrvP5.jpg); [alt.](https://i.ibb.co/Tb0dtL0/287592377.jpg))</sub>

In a section explaining Chinese punctuation, we have the above sentence.  Importantly, the sentences doesn't end in a 句号.  The other examples in this textbook likewise omit a 句号 after ellipses.  Judging from [this](http://www.chusan.com/zhongkao/65916.html), it seems it is standard to omit the 句号 after a 省略号.

Omitting the 句号 seems like a bad idea to me: it's unclear where the sentence ends; compare:

> 我去过了很多国家，日本、中国、美国……。加拿大、印度是我最喜欢的国家。
> 我去过了很多国家，日本、中国、美国……加拿大、印度是我最喜欢的国家。

For this reason, I strongly prefer to add a 句号, like how I would add a 引号 or 括号.

**Question**: Is it acceptable to add a 句号 (full stop 。) at the end of a sentence ending in a 省略号 (ellipsis ……)?

Comment: 句号 is necessary after a sentence ended with 括号 only (.......) 。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes. You can omit punctuations after/before 省略号，but you can also not omit them. If you think adding a 句号 is helpful for the meaning, just add them. Omitting punctuations near 省略号 is not necessary, just because most of the time the meaning of punctuations around the 省略号 can be expressed by 省略号, so many people omit them.